# -moz-max-content custom implementation

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` and I want to fix the width of the `ul` to content. Currently I use `-moz-max-content` but there is some problem in non-mozilla browsers.

How can I implement the `-moz-max-content`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `max-width:  intrinsic;`. This works for webkit browsers (Chrome & Safari).

Be aware that attributes starting with `-moz` are only working in Mozillas Firefox. The common prefixes are:

- `-moz` for Firefox
- `-webkit` for Webkit (mainly Chrome & Safari and a lot of the Chromium forks)
- `-ms` for IE10
- `-o` for Opera

As written at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms530811.aspx you can only define pixels or percentage. The `max-width` property itself is supported since IE7.

It might be that you can use a `max-width: 100%;` for IE, but I'm unsure if the results are the same.